# Очистка поля input при нажатии на checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть поле изначально оно пустое, при добавления товара в него вписывается сумма, как сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку сумма очищалась и поле становилось не активным.

```
 <div class="input-group">
    <input  type="text" style="height: 45px" name="sum_" placeholder="0.00" id="sum"  value="<?php echo $delete_sum; ?>" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <label for="danger"  class="btn btn-danger">Без наложки<input type="checkbox" id="danger" name="delivery_our_expense" class="badgebox"><span  class="badge">✓</span></label>
    </span>
</div>


<script>
$( "#danger" ).change( function () {

});
```

Никак ни магу сообразить как сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто, получаем нужный инпут, через его `id` и присваиваем пустое значение ну и проставляем атрибут `disabled` :

```js
var oldValue = 0;
$("#danger").change( function () {
  if($('#danger').is(':checked')){ 
    oldValue = $('#sum').val();
    $('#sum').val('').attr('disabled','disabled');
  } else {
    $('#sum').val(oldValue ).removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
    <input  type="text" style="height: 45px" name="sum_" placeholder="0.00" id="sum"  value="55.36" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <label for="danger"  class="btn btn-danger">Без наложки<input type="checkbox" id="danger" name="delivery_our_expense" class="badgebox"><span  class="badge">✓</span></label>
    </span>
</div>
```

UPD: добавил обратное действие :)

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Sender1050 если вы щитаете вопрос решенным, отметьте, если не сложно, один из верных ответов галочкой, дабы вопрос стал закрытым и в будущем люди с подобным вопросом могли найти ответ.

Comment: Да обязательно пишет что вы не можете  принять ответ сейчас пройдет время обязательно поставлю

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych  для полноты картины не плохо было бы еще добавить обратное действие :)

Comment: @Cheg а это мысль :)

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych условие, думаю, правильнее будет задать как `if ($('#danger').is(':checked'))`

Comment: @Cheg исправил, спс, я что первое вспомнил то и написал :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#danger" ).change( function () {
     $("#idИнпута").empty();
});
```

Comment: Функция `.empty()` удаляет все дочерние узлы, но не очищает значение `input`